# Use different single.php file based on condition

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I am customizing my WordPress site's theme and i need to use a different single.php file based on the condition.

Here is my user case, i need to design a competition page where i need to show entries submitted by the people.Entries can belong to various categories so it is not possible to trek them based on the categories.

I have created a tag (contest) and each entry belong to competition will be tagged with this tag, i can easily pick all entries based on this tag.

On the main navigation bar i have placed a link `"Contest"` which will take user to the contest page, on this page i am showing all submitted entries with short description and link to go to story page.

This is how i am displaying data on custom competition page

```
$ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');
$args = array(
    "tag" => getContestPageData('tag_name'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby'=> 'date',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
           );
 $posts=query_posts($args);
 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $random_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="left"/>
 </a>
```

moment user click on the anchor link it redirect user to the `single.php` page (if my understanding is correct)

I need Tweak main story page so as can design it with Competition theme in mind and i can do it with following option

1. Put some conditional logic in `single.php`
2. For all user who click story link on my custom page, land them on some other page say `compition-single.php`

Is this possible? please link to me appropriate resource or examples

Comment: So basically you want to know how to detect if the user has just come from a search listing? This sounds like you're trying to fix a solution, and you've not shown us the original problem. Perhaps if you explained why you want this and what you're trying to do that requires this?

Comment: Also your naming convention will cause issues, e.g. if you have a post with the ID 21, it will load single-21.php regardless of its category

Comment: @TomJNowell: well i am creating a page for some specific event and will show all event there, this even page is a custom page, so all i want is that if user click any post on this page it should use my `custom.php` page in place of `single.php`. I hope i am making some sense

Comment: Can you not tag or categorise those posts and use the system you used above? Or use a custom post type?

Comment: @TomJNowell: can you explain this approach a bit, sorry i only having limited knowledge of wordpress

Comment: You're already picking different templates based on category, can you not just put those posts in a new category and check against that?

Comment: @TomJNowell: sorry for confusion, that was just an example, please see my update post.

Comment: The snippet has no context, where is it? index.php? single.php? I thought you meant search as in what you get when you put stuff in a search box and it gives you results, but I suspect that's not what you mean? There's a real lack of information and **context** here

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase/reword? The words you're using are ambiguous, could mean multiple things

Comment: @TomJNowell: i updated question and hope it making sense nw

Answer (score 2):

In a previous edit you used:

```
if (in_category('21')) {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-21.php');
} else {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-29.php');
}
```

This is part of your solution, but before I continue, some important notes:

- Don't use include like that, instead `get_template_part('single-21');` works better
- Indent correctly
- This clashes with how IDs work in the template heirarchy. E.g. a post with ID 21 will always use `single-21.php` as its template

For your contest problem, what you want is:

```
if ( post has the tag 'contest' ) {
    get_template_part();
}
```

To determine if the post has the tag 'contest' use:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'tag' );
$is_contest = false;
foreach ( $terms as &$term ) {
    if ( $term->name == 'contest' ) {
        // Yes, this post has the contest tag
        $is_contest = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'd recommend you read up on these:

- register_post_type
- register_taxonomy
- get_template_part

I'd also strongly advise against hardcoding tags categories and numbers in your code, and that you get an editor that auto-indents your code, e.g. Sublime Text, PHPStorm, Netbeans, Komodo Edit, etc

Also as a last note, I **strongly** urge you not to use the query_posts function. Instead use WP_Query.